# vTiger Custmer Portal - Invoice Issure: .pdf download error

Tags: vtiger

Unfortunately we had a DB-Crash last week. therefore I used an backup copy of the system to rerun it. Everything goes well but the PDFMaker Pro. First I had license issues. PDFMaker did not accept my original license ID. This was fixed after un/reinstall of PDFMaker Pro. But, since then, when I activate PDFMaker Pro Invoice for the Customer Portal via Checkbox in the Invoice Settings of PDFMaker and hitting the subject link in Customer Portal for downloading the invoice, it generates an “index.pdf”. All settings like filename (for example invoice number) are ignored and the index.pdf does even not open. It returns an alert / warning in Adobe Acrobat: “Acrobat could not open pdf”.

The PDFMaker works in the Admin Interface. So everything is fine. But it does not work for the Customer Portal Invoice Module.

In Soap/customerportal.php I’ve found this lines of code:

```
    $fieldid = $adb->query_result($res,0,'invoiceid');
        //$fieldlabel = "(Download PDF)  ".$fieldlabel;
        $fieldvalue = '<a href="index.php?downloadfile=true&module=Invoice&action=index&id='.$fieldid.'">'.$fieldvalue.'</a>';
```

I don’t know if something is wrong with the code, or what else to check, finding the mistake. I’m looking for your advice fixing this bug. The PDFMaker Support is very slow and did not answer after 2 days. So, please if you have any idea, share it!

Thank you!
Jasper

Answer (score 0):

Well fixed it myself:

reinstall the soap/customerprotal.php if from PDFMaker necessary and check the premission rights of directories:

```
chmod 777 config.inc.php
chmod 777 tabdata.php
chmod 777 install.php
chmod 777 parent_tabdata.php
chmod 777 cache/
chmod 777 cache/images/
chmod 777 cache/import/
chmod 777 storage/
chmod 777 install/
chmod 777 user_privileges/
chmod 777 Smarty/cache/
chmod 777 Smarty/templates_c/
chmod 777 modules/Emails/templates/
chmod 777 modules/
chmod 777 cron/modules/
chmod 777 test/vtlib/
chmod 777 backup/
chmod 777 Smarty/templates/modules/
chmod 777 test/wordtemplatedownload/
chmod 777 test/product/
chmod 777 test/user/
chmod 777 test/contact
chmod 777 test/logo
chmod 777 logs/
chmod 777 modules/Webmails/tmp/
```

and index.pdf means the customer has not premission rights.
Hope this can help in the future.

Jasper